# How can i get the public key of the Candy Machine of collection

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, metaplex, solana-program-library, candy-machine

Please Help i want to  get NFT Mint Addresses and this function below return what i want but it requires the candy machine id :

```
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl, PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';
import bs58 from 'bs58';

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('mainnet-beta'));
const MAX_NAME_LENGTH = 32;
const MAX_URI_LENGTH = 200;
const MAX_SYMBOL_LENGTH = 10;
const MAX_CREATOR_LEN = 32 + 1 + 1;
const MAX_CREATOR_LIMIT = 5;
const MAX_DATA_SIZE = 4 + MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 4 + MAX_SYMBOL_LENGTH + 4 + MAX_URI_LENGTH + 2 + 1 + 4 + MAX_CREATOR_LIMIT * MAX_CREATOR_LEN;
const MAX_METADATA_LEN = 1 + 32 + 32 + MAX_DATA_SIZE + 1 + 1 + 9 + 172;
const CREATOR_ARRAY_START = 1 + 32 + 32 + 4 + MAX_NAME_LENGTH + 4 + MAX_URI_LENGTH + 4 + MAX_SYMBOL_LENGTH + 2 + 1 + 4;

const TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM = new PublicKey('metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s');
const candyMachineId = new PublicKey('ENTER_YOUR_CANDY_MACHINE_ID_HERE');

const getMintAddresses = async (firstCreatorAddress: PublicKey) => {
  const metadataAccounts = await connection.getProgramAccounts(
    TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM,
    {
      // The mint address is located at byte 33 and lasts for 32 bytes.
      dataSlice: { offset: 33, length: 32 },

      filters: [
        // Only get Metadata accounts.
        { dataSize: MAX_METADATA_LEN },

        // Filter using the first creator.
        {
          memcmp: {
            offset: CREATOR_ARRAY_START,
            bytes: firstCreatorAddress.toBase58(),
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  );

  return metadataAccounts.map((metadataAccountInfo) => (
    bs58.encode(metadataAccountInfo.account.data)
  ));
};

getMintAddresses(candyMachineId);
```

https://solanacookbook.com/references/nfts.html#how-to-get-the-owner-of-an-nft

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run candy-machine-v2-cli.ts upload, it should print the newly created candy machine ID into your console.

However, given that you searching for creators, what you actually need to use the candy machine *creator* id associated with the candy machine. This is different from the candy machine Id itself.

You can find the candy machine creator id in the metadata of any of minted assets.  The candy machine creator id will be the first in the list creators with creator share of 0.

Comment: I am grateful for your help.